# Why can't type `intersection of an interface with a property and an interface with index signature` be assigned to an object with just the property?

Tags: typescript

Why can't I define `lastById` below with only the property `pairsByIntOrderId`?

Isn't the type TransactionsByIdState: has property `pairsByIntOrderId` and can optionally have additional properties of type string that map to Transaction?

```
interface Transaction {
  amount: number,
  id: string
}

interface PairTransactionsById {
  [id: string]: {
    amount1: number,
    amount2: number,
  }
}
export type TransactionsByIdState = {
  [id: string]: Transaction;
} & { pairsByIntOrderId: PairTransactionsById };

const lastById: TransactionsByIdState = { pairsByIntOrderId: {} };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I define lastById below with only the property pairsByIntOrderId?

Because an index signature enforces that *all* properties [match its return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

With type `TransactionsByIdState` you are basically saying that all string properties are obligated to have a `Transaction` type. This condition applies to property 
`pairsByIntOrderId` as well, which is added via intersection.

`pairsByIntOrderId` is also declared to be of type `PairTransactionsById`. Because `PairTransactionsById` is not assignable to `Transaction`, you in a way have created a "never-fulfilling" type here. The only thing that prevents the compiler from emitting an error is, that intersection intentionally can never create errors (compare [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24970#issuecomment-397435307) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13986#issuecomment-278826312)).

Having said that, a concrete solution depends on your use case and type requirements. You can check out and subscribe to this [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for hybrid types with  index signature + properties. If `Transaction` and `PairTransactionsById` are intended to be incompatible (which seems to be the case here), they should be stored independently. Also [separating index signature from explicit properties](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html#design-pattern-nested-index-signature) in general is a good rule of thumb to have stronger typings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an empty object to `pairsByIntOrderId` since it's type expects two fields - `amount` and `id`. TypeScript expects them since they are not optional. There are two ways to solve it:

either you could make both of the fields optional;

```
interface Transaction {
   amount?: number;
   id?: string;
}
```

or use `Partial` type, which constructs a new type with every field optional;

```
[id: string]: Partial<Transaction>;
```

Comment: Actually `pairsByIntOrderId` is of type `PairTransactionsById` which is an object with index signature.